# How do I remove the number in the end of a reference?

Tags: bibtex, back-referencing

How do I remove the page number in which a reference was cited using bibtex and natbib?

My references look like:

```
Alfred Renyi. On a new axiomatic theory of probability. Acta Mathematica Hungarica, 
6(3):285–335, 1955. 3, 10, 12, 18, 22
```

But I want them to look like:

```
Alfred Renyi. On a new axiomatic theory of probability. Acta Mathematica Hungarica, 
6(3):285–335, 1955.
```

I am using natbib and my bibliography style is plainnat:

```
\usepackage{natbib}
\bibliographystyle{plainnat}
```

I found this [link](http://www.latex-community.org/forum/viewtopic.php?f=50&t=9547) where the guy solved the same problem removing the option backref from the hyperref package. But I am not using this package (maybe I am using it indirectly?).

**How to remove the page numbers at the end of the references?**

Comment: Can you show the code please?

Comment: I was using a class that was using this package. I deleted the pagebackref option and it is working now. Thanks.

Comment: Great!. Can we close this question then, if you don't mind?

Comment: yes, we can close this question.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it was a class/package clash cleared by removing a certain option given in the comments.